# Multiple images on a background

Tags: css

I am trying to create a page with multiple background images, using this CSS code:

```
body {
 background-image:url(../i/bg_bf.jpg), url(../../../../test.png) ;
 background-position:  top center, bottom left;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 padding-top:3px;
}
```

It works fine with Firefox, but does not show neither images in IE.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

Multiple backgrounds/images aren't supported by IE, at least before IE9, [they're a CSS3 feature](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/), you can find them [in the spec here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image) with [specifics here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering).

Answer (score 0):

you might need to use wrappers

```
<body>
  <div id="windowWrapper">
```

CSS:

```
body {
 background-image:url(../i/bg_bf.jpg) no-repeat top center;
 padding-top:3px;
}

#windowWrapper {
 background-image:url(../i/test.jpg) no-repeat top center;
}
```